# "<tensor> is not an element of this graph." when saving model weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

i am hosting an API(using flask) of a machine learning model using keras.

i am using an API to send the data and run Ml model.I am also trying to save the keras sequential model using json and h5 for weights.

```
model_json = classifier.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

classifier.save_weights("model.h5",overwrite=True)
```

Every time i host the API, it works properly only for the first api call (Which includes the saving the model). But from the next call it throws me the following error.

> ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("dense_1/kernel:0", shape=(41, 41), dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph.)

i tried to debug it and found the the problem is occurring at

```
classifier.save_weights("model.h5",overwrite=True)
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks